# ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: python, pandas

My function is below

```
def fu1():
    return ("func1")

def fu2():
    return ("func2")
```

My Code is below

```
def test_func(x):
    if (df['response'].str['detected'] == True & df['response_url1'].str['is_doc1'] == True):
        fu1()
    elif (df['response'].str['detected'] == True & df['response_url2'].str['is_doc1'] == True):
        fu2()
    else:
        return ("oops no response")
```

while applying function

`df.compare = df.apply(test_func,axis = 1)`

got below error

ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')

df['response'].str['detected']

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: response, dtype: bool
```

adding sample data (head(2)

```
response,response_url1,response_url2
{'detected': True, 'bool': True}, {'is_doc1': False, 'is_doc2': True},{'is_doc1': True, 'is_doc2': True}
{'detected': False, 'bool': True},{'is_doc1': True, 'is_doc2': True},{'is_doc1': False, 'is_doc2': True}
```

expected out
`df.compare` = `func2`, `oops no response`

Comment: Please dont make this as duplicate, i already checked  stack overflow links

Comment: already done any() and all()

Comment: Did you searc for the error message?

Comment: The error messages tell you what the problem is. df['response'].str['detected'] contains four booleans, so the equals comparison is ambiguous. Do you want all of the entries in the series to be true or at least one?

Comment: How did you use `any()` or `all()`?

Comment: yes g, pd.Series, or a pd.Series with a value, any or all is required, i have tried that

Comment: atlast (df['response'].str['detected'] == True & df['response_url'].str['is_doc1'] == True).any()

Comment: i want to compare in series, each column value corresponds to other column

Comment: Can you include a minimal example of the DataFrame? Enough to reproduce the problem? …  [mcve]

Comment: `if df['response'].str['detected'].any() and …`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all those *expressions* evaluate to boolean Series' like your single example - try

```
def test_func(x):
    if df['response'].str['detected'].all() and df['response_url'].str['is_doc1'].all():
        fu1()
    elif (df['response'].str['detected'].all() and df['response_url2'].str['is_doc1'].all():
        fu2()
    else:
        return ("oops no response")
```

or

```
def test_func(x):
    q = df['response'].str['detected'] == df['response_url'].str['is_doc1']
    r = (df['response'].str['detected'] == df['response_url2'].str['is_doc1']

    if q.all():
        fu1()
    elif r.all():
        fu2()
    else:
        return ("oops no response")
```

or using `.equals()`

```
def test_func(x):
    if df['response'].str['detected'].equals(df['response_url'].str['is_doc1']):
        fu1()
    elif df['response'].str['detected'].equals(df['response_url2'].str['is_doc1']):
        fu2()
    else:
        return ("oops no response")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def test_func(x):
    if ((df['response'].str['detected'] == True) & (df['response_url'].str['is_doc1'] == True)):
        fu1()
    elif ((df['response'].str['detected'] == True) & (df['response_url2'].str['is_doc1'] == True)):
        fu2()
    else:
        return ("oops no response")
```

Comment: same error g, i want to compare in series, each column value corresponds to other column

Comment: could you provide sample data?

Comment: added the sample data